Unable to import certificates to Google Chrome
Hardware : Google Chromebook Plus
OS: Version 125.0.6422.140 (Official Build) (64-bit)
I am unable to install client certificates (.crt,.pfx,.p7b) to my chrome browser. Every time I try to import a certificate, I get certificate import error "Unknown Error". I have a Google Workspace account and am the administrator of that workspace account and haven't made any security changes which would prevent me from importing certificates.
on my Chrome browser
settings > privacy & security > security > advanced > manage certificates > import > select an SSL Certificate > import > "unknown error"
